# Eclipse anonymous class folding

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, anonymous-class

Is there an Eclipse plugin that folds anonymous classes?

Preferably something that works like Intellij's closure folding: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/03/closure-folding-in-intellij-idea-9-maia/

I've looked at lambda4jdt, but it does not support newer versions of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse Preferences, check "Inner types" as element to be initially folded:

[image: Inner types folding screenshot]

Effect:

[image: Before folding]

is initially shown as

[image: After folding]

Comment: This just hides the body of the inner class, which is not very useful. Intellij and lambda4jdt still show the body of the inner class when folded.

Comment: @burnsy I see. Unfortunately, there is no further development planned for lambda4jdt, and I can't find another plugin that provides a similar functionality.

Comment: Same here. Maybe everybody assumed that Java 8 lambdas were right around the corner. :)

Comment: @burnsy I think so :). Hopefully someone else knows another way - or gets motivated to implement one...